# Excel/VBA: When cell changes, change another cell with different date format

Tags: excel, tfs, vba

I want to change an excel cell when another cell changes.
MY data comes from TFS and the date it returns is a long date (`2018/02/02  12:07:33 AM`) but the column next to it needs to change to the short date (`2018/02/02`)
There can be newly added rows at any time.
Using the following works fine but as soon as a new row is added the short date is blank:

```
=DATE(YEAR(E3);MONTH(E3);DAY(E3))
```

Is it possible to do it without VBA, if not how would I achieve this with VBA.

```
|A1                      |A2               |
|Long Date               |Short Date       |
|2018/02/02  12:07:33 AM |2018/02/02       |
```

The list from TFS will change every week and the long dates may also change per day or per week. At first the long date will be empty, when a user presses a specific button then the query from TFS will update the long date cell.

Comment: just use `=A1` and format the cell as a short date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel\VBA : So what i did is:

```
'Add smalldate to all items in the items page
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim RowNumber As String
    Dim ColumnNumber As String: ColumnNumber = "F"
    Dim FixedVariable As String: FixedVariable = "F3:"

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    RowNumber = ColumnNumber & LastRow

    Dim RangeValue As String: RangeValue = FixedVariable + RowNumber
    Range(RangeValue).Formula = "=DATE(YEAR(E3),MONTH(E3),DAY(E3))"
```

Works like a charm, I need to use better naming conventions!

Answer (score 2):

If I got your question right, the solution seems to be quite simple.

Use the formula in Cell A2: "=A1"

Right-click on the Cell A2 and select 'Format Cells...'
Choose 'Custom' option in Category and then type in "yyyy/mm/dd" for the Type

That should be it. Since the cells are linked by formula, they should automatically update as long as the Calculation Options is set to 'Automatic'

Comment: Ok that works but what will happen if a new row is added automatically from my tfs query? The the short date will be empty?

Comment: You have two options from here. Either change the A2 formula to something like "=IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",A1)" and fill down to any number of rows you would like. This takes care of only the aesthetics.
However if you wish for it to be actually dynamic you would need to use VBA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),DAY(A1))
```

Formatted to `yyyy/mm/dd`.

Comment: I have that formula for now. But because it is a tfs integrated excel workbook but this wont auto populate newly added rows

Comment: @Ruan you can either run the formula down the whole column or use VBA to place the formula or value as the data changes.

Comment: Is it possible do this automatically in stead of dragging it down every time?

Comment: @Ruan - You could use VBA - of if your data is in a column, just double click the bottom right of the formula cell to quick-fill.

Comment: @Ruan no,  You can put `=IF(A1<>"",A1,"")` Drag the formula down the whole column and format the whole column as short date.  Then until then cell next to it is filled it will show an empty cell